# CLLocationManager Overheating iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager, augmented-reality

I'm making an app with augmented reality. 
Basically what I have is a screen with image from camera, radar view and some markers on the screen. 
I'm using CLLocationManager to get updates on my heading and location. 
I need heading updates always turned on, because the radar rotation depends on it. I'm using location updates to get my position and based on that I'm looking for markers to show. 
The problem is that when I've got both turned on the iPhone is overheating a little over some time (10 +- minutes). I've got the accuracy set to every 100 metres and distance filter to 100. 
Should I set up a timer to stop and start updating of location to prevent the overheating (and probably save some battery life too)? Is there any other approach for this? 
Thanks for advices.

Comment: It certainly sounds like you're overworking the CPU somehow.  I once had an app get caught in a CPU loop on a Nokia phone and it overheated enough to soften the glue holding the screen together.  Make sure that your app isn't in a "spin loop" somewhere when it should instead be waiting for events.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think it's that bad :), I mean it's warm (iphone doesn't really heat often so it's weird for me to see it warm) in the top right corner where the camera is (probably something with core location also). I'll check the time profiler as Kendall suggested and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good time to user the "Time Profiler" instrument.  I'm sure using GPS is responsible for some of the heat but you could easily have some other part of the code that is using the CPU or GPU too heavily.

There's also a OpenGL performance tool, I would look at that to see if you can find any parts that are taxing the GPU too much.

Another possibility is to look into using AVFoundation to get the camera image, and see if you can specify less expensive preview parameters for the video image you are overlaying.

Answer (score -1):

```
    - (id) init 
    {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self; 

}
return self;
    }
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);
[self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)managerdidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

{     
[self.delegate locationError:error];
NSLog(@"Error Error: %@",[error description]);
}
```

These delegate function will b call in MyCLConrolleer.m class.

Allocate this class in ViewController class like this.

```
     locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
locationController.delegate = self;
[locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
 showCurrentLocation = NO;
```

Delegate functions in View Controller class

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self getLocationNameWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
  }
```